# Resize two dimensional vector in a class

Tags: c++, vector, resize

I'm trying to resize a vector in the class. I don't know where is the error. Hope you can help me.

This is my code:

```
class State {
private:
    vector<int> numbers;
    int score;

public:
    int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    void setScore(int score) {
        this->score = score;
    }
    int getSize () {
        return this->numbers.size();
    }
    void setSize(int size) {
        this->numbers.clear();
        this->numbers.resize(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            this->numbers[i].resize(size);
    }
};
```

When I try to compile, I get this error:

```
In file included from ./power.cpp:11:
./power.hpp:45:24: error: member reference base type 'value_type' (aka 'int') is not a structure or union
                    this->numbers[i].resize(size);
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! please add your main() routine to make it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Btw - your vector<int> is technically not "two-dimensional" , thus you try to resize a plain `int` luring at `numbers[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector<int> numbers;
```

declares a one-dimensional vector. In the line

```
this->numbers[i].resize(size);
```

you assume that `numbers[i]` is itself a vector, which is not the case (it is an `int`). What you probably want is to declare

```
vector<vector<int>> numbers;
```

or "simulate" the 2D vector as a 1D flatten vector (in general faster) but making sure to map from 2D to 1D and vice versa.

Comment: For mentioning `"simulate" [..] as 1D vector` ++vote: That vector<vector<....>>> contortionism is a pain in the eye.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks for your help :)